# Java - How do I get the output to show trailing zeros of a double?

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
double area = 6.60;    
System.out.println(area);
```

This gives the output 6.6

How can I make the output be 6.60?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 double x = 6.60;
 System.out.printf("%.2f",x);
```

> 6.60

- The .0 specifies the precision. Number is rounded off according to
  the precision specified here. (e.g. if you want 2 decimal places you
  would specify .2)
- The f specifies it's a floating point - including doubles (d is for
  decimal integer)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
    double area = 6.60;
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(area));
```

Output:

> 6.60